# How to take a screenshot of active previous window from angular web application?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there any way to take screenshot of previous active window from our web application? As of now I'm using `html2canvas` to take screenshot of current window of my webapp, but I need to take a screenshot of my previous active window.(Ex : if I open eclipse first and then open my webapp, from webapp I want to take a screenshot of previous active window means eclipse.)
Is it possible from angular or javascript?

Comment: Nope. It's not even possible to take a screenshot of the previous web page -- once it's gone it's gone -- but what you're talking about is even more not-possible (your web browser are not capable of taking screenshots of a different application, for obvious security reasons!)

Comment: Read [ask] please

Comment: @DanielBeck thank you for u r feedback.

Answer (score 1):

No.

JavaScript running in a web browser is sandboxed and instances where it can interact with applications outside the browser are extremely limited. Taking screenshots of other applications is not one of the exceptions.